# How can we blockquote Arabic on mobile?

Tags: discussion, formatting

When I want to edit a question or answer to blockquote, I cannot blockquote the Arabic verses and hadith.

Is there a way on a mobile phone to blockquote the Arabic?

Answer (score 2):

Just prefix each line of the blockquote with a greater-than sign (">"). For example, typing:

```
> This is blockquoted

> And so is this

> وهذا هو بلوككوتد أيضا
```

Would render as:

> This is blockquoted
>
> And so is this
>
> وهذا هو بلوككوتد أيضا

Comment: I know how to blockquote but Arabic starts from the right and goes to the left, so could you please edit your answer with an example of blockquoting in Arabic

Comment: @Armaan Sounds like that might be an issue with your phone's RTL support than with Stack Exchange itself; I've added an example where I typed an Arabic line on my own mobile (pardon the questionable Google translated grammar) prefixed with ">", as described, and it's rendering fine. You may need to add more details to your question to pinpoint exactly *where* the root problem is before anyone can really help.

Comment: @Armaan I know it is pretty exhausting to paste Arabic text to an blockqoute sometimes.
My tips for you is to you is to write like 3 rows of tags (>) FIRST, then paste your Arabic text in the middle tag, that allows you to go up and down easier to edit text above or below the Arabic text, or even to edit the Arabic text itself.